# pinball targets - wont reset

Tags: button, arduino

Im an artist, not a programmer. But i'm making a pinball game with an Arduino, and I do not have a programmer, so I'm learning what I can to make this work.

I'm trying to write a code that does this: 
- 3 targets (buttons) that when hit, they give points, and light an LED. 
- If the same button is hit a second time, it will still give points, and the LED stays lit. 
- If ALL 3 lights are lit at the same time, there is a bonus score given, and ALL 3 lights turn off.

I tried using the Arduino forums but the best advice I could get out of them was "Go learn to code."

I have been told to learn about 'arrays' and I have tried but I'm having some serious trouble wrapping my head around it. If it is possible to do this with just 'IF' and 'ELSE' statements I would really prefer to do things the long and inefficient way.

Here is my current code. Currently I have 4 lights on my breadboard. Light #4 (D) is lit right away for debug reasons. Each of the other 3 lights (ABC) will light when their button is pushed. When All 3 lights are lit, (D) light will go out, but (ABC) remain lit.  I need them to go out when (D) does. and I don't know why they wont. I know the code recognizes that all 3 are HIGH. Because (D) goes LOW.  I don't know why (ABC) won't go LOW as well.

```
// 3 TARGET SCORE FUNCTION. 
// WHEN A TARGET IS HIT IT LIGHTS UP AND PROVIDES POINTS.
// IF A TARGET IS HIT AGAIN WHILE IT IS ALREADY LIT, IT STILL SCORES POINTS AND STAYS LIT.
// WHEN ALL 3 TARGETS ARE LIT THEY FLASH AND PROVIDE A JACKPOT
// WHEN JACKPOT IS PROVIDED ALL LIGHTS TURN OFF. READY TO BE ACTIVATED AGAIN. 

int dropButtonA = 2;         // the number of the input pin
int dropButtonB = 3;        
int dropButtonC = 4;  

int dropLightA = 11;       // the number of the output pin
int dropLightB = 12;     
int dropLightC = 13; 
int dropLightD = 10;     

int stateA = LOW;      // the current state of the output pin
int stateB = LOW;      
int stateC = LOW;   
int stateD = LOW;  

int readingA;   // the current reading from the input pin
int readingB;
int readingC; 

int previousA = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin
int previousB = LOW;   
int previousC = LOW;    

long time = 0;         // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounce = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers

void setup()
{
  pinMode(dropButtonA, INPUT);
  pinMode(dropButtonB, INPUT);
  pinMode(dropButtonC, INPUT);

  pinMode(dropLightA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dropLightB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dropLightC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dropLightD, OUTPUT);
    }

void loop()
{

  //droptarget_01//

   readingA = digitalRead(dropButtonA);

        if (readingA == HIGH && previousA == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {

        stateA = HIGH;

      time = millis();    
    }

    digitalWrite(dropLightA, stateA);

    previousA = readingA;

  //droptarget_02//

   readingB = digitalRead(dropButtonB);

        if (readingB == HIGH && previousB == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {

            stateB = HIGH;

          time = millis();    
        }

        digitalWrite(dropLightB, stateB);

        previousB = readingB;

   //droptarget_03//

   readingC = digitalRead(dropButtonC);

        if (readingC == HIGH && previousC == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {

            stateC = HIGH;

          time = millis();    
        }

        digitalWrite(dropLightC, stateC);

        previousC = readingC;


  //RESET TARGETS - BONUS SCORE
if (digitalRead(dropLightA)==HIGH && digitalRead(dropLightB)==HIGH && digitalRead(dropLightC)==HIGH)
{
  digitalWrite(dropLightA, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dropLightB, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dropLightC, LOW);
  digitalWrite(dropLightD, LOW);
}
else 
{
  digitalWrite(dropLightD, HIGH);
 }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable named "stateX" does not change when ABC goes `LOW`. You need to add these statements to the "//RESET TARGETS - BONUS SCORE" loop when the condition is true:

```
stateA = LOW;
stateB = LOW;
stateC = LOW;
stateD = LOW;
```

IMHO you do not need to use arrays when there are only four items- clarity of code (esp. to the author) has value. However, I think that the variables "stateX" and "previousX" are redundant; if you did not have both you would not have this bug.

Also, I would recommend using the previously read value of the pins for the loop test at "//RESET TARGETS - BONUS SCORE":

```
if (readingA == HIGH && readingB == HIGH && readingC == HIGH)
```

With your current code you read the values of the pins twice during the loop. In this case there is a chance the value of the pins could change during the loop and you could get *really* confusing results.